# How do I make my reCAPTCHA v2 box scale dynamically according to device size?

Tags: css, responsive-design, recaptcha, next.js13

My reCAPTCHA-v2 box is unable to scale dynamically, it is fixed in width no matter what styling I have applied to it. I have tried using iFrame to display it as using iFrame will solve the issue of sizing it dynamically but was encountered with Content Security Policy issue as well. I have also tried some online examples of using transform to scale the size accordingly, but was unsuccessful as well. Your help is greatly much appreciated thank you!

```
"use client"

import '@/app/globals.css';

import { useState } from 'react';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";


export default function LoginPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [activeFormIndex, setActiveFormIndex] = useState(0);
    const [recaptchaToken, setRecaptchaToken] = useState(null);

    const handleRecaptchaVerify = (token: any) => {
        setRecaptchaToken(token);
    };

    const onSubmit = async (values: any, loginType: any) => {
        const credentials = {
            username: values.username,
            password: values.password,
            reCaptchaToken: recaptchaToken,
            redirect: false,
         };

        let signInType = "";

        switch (loginType) {
            case "customer":
                signInType = "customer-credentials";
                break;
            case "manager":
                signInType = "manager-credentials";
                break;
            case "admin":
                signInType = "admin-credentials";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        const result = await signIn(signInType, credentials);

        if (result?.error) {
            console.log(`Fail ${loginType} Login`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Success ${loginType} Login`);
            router.push(`/dashboard/${loginType}`);
        }
    };

    const buttons = [
        { label: 'Customer', index: 0 },
        { label: 'Manager', index: 1 },
        { label: 'Admin', index: 2 }
    ];

    const headerText = buttons[activeFormIndex].label + " Login";

    const logoImage = activeFormIndex === 0 ? "logo1.svg" : activeFormIndex === 1 ? "logo2.svg" : "logo3.svg";

return (
    <div className="flex min-h-full flex-1 flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">
        <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
            <img className="mx-auto h-20 w-30" src={logoImage} alt="Logo" />
            <h2 className="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-gray-900">
                {headerText}
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
            <div className="flex justify-center">
                <div className="flex-grow flex">
                    {buttons.map(({ label, index }) => (
                        <button
                            key={index}
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => setActiveFormIndex(index)}
                            className={`py-3 px-4 flex-grow ${index === activeFormIndex
                                ? 'bg-blue-500 text-black focus:ring-0'
                                : 'bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400'
                                } border font-medium align-middle hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 transition-all text-sm ${index === 0 ? 'rounded-l-lg' : ''} ${index === buttons.length - 1 ? 'rounded-r-lg' : ''}`}
                        >
                            {label}
                        </button>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-10">
                {buttons.map(({ label, index }) => (
                    <div key={index} className={index === activeFormIndex ? 'block' : 'hidden'}>
                        <Form
                            className="space-y-6"
                            initialValues={{ remember: true }}
                            autoComplete="off"
                            method="post"
                            onFinish={(values) => onSubmit(values, label.toLowerCase())}
                        >
                            <Form.Item
                                name="username"
                                rules={[
                                    { required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' },
                                ]}
                                hasFeedback
                            >
                                <Input placeholder="Username" />
                            </Form.Item>

                            <Form.Item
                                name="password"
                                rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }]}
                                hasFeedback
                            >
                                <Input.Password placeholder="Password" />
                            </Form.Item>

                            <Form.Item
                                name="recaptcha"
                                rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please verify RECAPTCHA!' }]}
                                hasFeedback
                            >
                         
                                <ReCAPTCHA
                                    sitekey="abc123"
                                    onChange={handleRecaptchaVerify}
                                />

                            </Form.Item>

                            <Form.Item>
                                <Button
                                    type="primary"
                                    className="flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                                    htmlType="submit"
                                >
                                    Sign In
                                </Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div >
);
```

}

Comment: Why do you need it to scale? It’s designed to fit on narrow screens.

Comment: @BrettDonald, I am not able to fit on smaller mobile devices that have a lower width